# How to fix the error appropriate loader to handle this file type in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

```
data = [{
 img: '01d'
}, {
 img: '02d'
}]

data && data.map((item) => (
      <img src={require(`./icons/${item['img']}.svg`).default} />
))
```

I have an error which is the `Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)`
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. which I'm trying to display the icon based on the `data img`

this is my directory:

```
directory
 - src/
 - src/location/
    - index.tsx
 - src/icons/
    - 01d.svg
    - 02d.svg
    - 03d.svg
```

but when I try the `` require(`./icons/01d.svg`).default `` its working. but What I'm trying to do to is to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next.js to serve [static files](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Store the svg files under your public directory rather than under src.

Then you can generate URLs pointing to those static files in your react template, instead of `require`ing them:

```
data && data.map((item) => (
      <img src={`/icons/${item['img']}.svg`} />
))
```

Comment: I have around 20, then I'll just do it like that?

Comment: Actually, im going to give you some different advice.

Comment: Maybe I should used the first option that you posted. cause I'm trying to do is without putting the images in public folder.

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to remember to add a new line requiring the new image if you ever add more svgs. With the public folder, you add a new svg file and it will still work. Up to you!